# How do I route to a controller action when I'm in a routing closure in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

If I type `domain/something/someaction/10` I will catch this with the following routing rule:

```
Route::get('/{resource}/someaction/{id}', function($resource,$id){
    //do something
});
```

Now, inside this closure I want to forward this request to a controller's action. But it could be anything, for instance:

```
$controller_name = transformThisResource($resource).'Controller';
$controller = new $controller_name;
$controller->someaction($id);
```

The particular problem I am having is that there are around 30 controllers in this project and 3 tasks performed by 3 actions in each of of them behave exactly the same. With a functionality such as the one described above I would need only 3 rules in my routes file.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it makes much sense to call a controller's method from another controller's method.

I think that your `transformThisResource()` method should actually return a redirect path. For example, Let's say that when your user visits `domain/something/someaction/10` **(resides within controller A)** you want to execute some code which resides within another controller's method **(hereinafter referred as controller B)** which responds to the URI `/the/right/controller/method` or `{resource}/right/controller/{id}`. what I would do in this case is return a redirect from **controller A**:

```
public function controllerADefaultResponder($resource, $id)
{
    return redirect(mapToUri($resource, $id));
}
```

The above code may redirect to a link such as `/the/right/controller/method?resource=domain/something&id=10` or `domain/something/right/controller/10`. The only difference between the two links is how you choose to pass the data from request to request. One is using route arguments and the other is using GET parameters.